# wxpython custom titlebar with resize border

Tags: wxpython

i'm currently trying to implement a custom titlebar for my wxpython frame.

When I set `Frame(... style=wx.NO_BORDER,...)` I actually get the visual result I want to have, however the Frame is then not resizable.

If I add the style `wx.RESIZE_BORDER` it's possible to resize the frame and the small border around the frame would be no problem, but the border on the top of the window is actually quite large and noticeable (see screenshot).

Is there any way to get an equal sized border that can be used to resize the frame?

Minimal working example:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
#frame = wx.Frame(None,style=wx.NO_BORDER)
frame = wx.Frame(None,style=wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
#frame = wx.Frame(None,style=wx.NO_BORDER|wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
frame.SetPosition((100,100))
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `wx.MiniFrame`

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
frame = wx.MiniFrame(None, style=wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Would give you:

[image]

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
frame = wx.MiniFrame(None, -1, "Miniframe", style=wx.CAPTION|wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Would give:

[image]

The black border is merely part of the screen shot, to allow you to see the frame outline.
Note the Reverse `L` in the bottom righthand corner. this is used to re-size the window.

> This class supports the following styles:

wx.ICONIZE: Display the frame iconized (minimized) (Windows only).

wx.CAPTION: Puts a caption on the frame.

wx.MINIMIZE: Identical to wx.ICONIZE.

wx.MINIMIZE_BOX: Displays a minimize box on the frame (Windows and Motif only).

wx.MAXIMIZE: Displays the frame maximized (Windows only).

wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX: Displays a maximize box on the frame (Windows and Motif only).

wx.CLOSE_BOX: Displays a close box on the frame.

wx.STAY_ON_TOP: Stay on top of other windows (Windows only).

wx.SYSTEM_MENU: Displays a system menu (Windows and Motif only).

wx.RESIZE_BORDER: Displays a resizable border around the window.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that class exists. On my Windows10 System, MiniFrame gives the same result as the normal Frame, any idea if this is bound to a specific system? On which system did you make your screenshots?

Comment: These screenshots are taken from an Ubuntu Linux system. Window appearance is inevitably tied to the OS and to some degree the chosen theme.